# Could not execute method for android:onClick?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a Login Page by verifying the email and password already in the database.But,A Fatal Exception occurs.

Here is my LoginActivity.java ,myDbHelper.java ,activity_login.xml and the logcat error.

The logcat error is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION:main
    Process:no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox,PID:9052
    java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    Could not
    execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19888)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(
    Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
    Caused by:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(
    Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19888) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(
    Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706) 
    Caused by:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:near ".":

    syntax error(code 1):,while compiling:select *
    from contacts
    where email = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText

    {
        1d 2 b15f4 VFED..CL ........ 0, 72 - 1080, 208 #7f 090085 app:
    id / editText_mail
    }

    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(
    Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
    at no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myDbAdapter.getEmail(myDbAdapter.java:208)
    at no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.LoginActivity.login(LoginActivity.java:41)
```

My LoginActivity.java:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView email;
    TextView pass;

    private no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myDbAdapter mydb;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_mail);
        pass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText_pass);
        mydb = new no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myDbAdapter(this);

    }

    public void register(View v) {
        Intent goToSecond = new Intent();
        goToSecond.setClass(this, Register_Page.class);
        startActivity(goToSecond);
    }

    public void login(View v) {
        Cursor c1 = mydb.getEmail(email);
        Cursor c2 = mydb.getpass(pass);
        if (c1 != null & c2 != null) {
            Intent goToSecond = new Intent();
            goToSecond.setClass(this, Profile.class);
            startActivity(goToSecond);
        } else
            message(getApplicationContext(), "not valid user");
    }
}
```

The myDbHelper.java (getEmail and getpass methods ) are as follows:

```
 public Cursor getEmail(TextView email)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where email="+email+"",null);
        return cursor;
    }
    public Cursor getpass(TextView pass)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where password="+pass+"",null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

What is causing the app to crash?
Where is the possible error?

I did the suggested changes .But now the logcat error shows:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@gmail": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from contacts where email=kingervinny@gmail.com
```

How can i rectify this??

Comment: got an error in logcat @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Kindly check my answer. Rectify your `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Rectify **`SELECT`** Statement.

> SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:

Use **`getText().toString()`**. Your  **`SELECT`** statement will be.

```
 Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts  where email='"+email.getText().toString()+"'",null);
```

And

```
 Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts  where password='"+pass.getText().toString()+"'",null);
```

Comment: Ok.let me inform

Comment: applied the suggestion but encountered another error which i have edited in the question.@IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: @vinnykinger use `"select * from contacts  where email='"+email.getText().toString()+"'"`

Comment: @vinnykinger Did you check my answer ??

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mail);
EditText  pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_pass);
Cursor c1 = mydb.getEmail(email.getText());
Cursor c2 = mydb.getpFass(pass.getText());

AND  
 Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where email='"+email.getText().toString()+"'",null);

Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where password='"+pass.getText().toString()+"'",null);
```

Comment: applied the suggestion but encountered another error which i have edited in the question. @Zezariya Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

> What is causing the app to crash?Where is the possible error?

Its the `email` and `pass` causing problem, because sql query is always in string and your `email` and `pass` are not `String` but `TextView`, hence the crash

Change `myDbHelper.java` to:

```
public Cursor getEmail(TextView email)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where email='"+email.getText().toString()+"'",null);    //Added getText().toString()
        return cursor;
    }
    public Cursor getpass(TextView pass)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where password='"+pass.getText()+"'",null);    //Added getText().toString()
        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: applied the suggestion but encountered another error which i have edited in the question.@Firoz Memon

Comment: Add single quote `'` before and after double quotes like `email='"+email.getText().toString()+"'"`  Also I have edited my answer wrt email and password both